# Get most viewed products

Tags: magento2, reports, view

How do I get most viewed products in custom Magento2? I already found the workaround for top sellers but I do not get nothing about views

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Magento 2 shows the most viewed product in **Magento Admin** > **DASHBOARD** > choose tab **Most Viewed Products**. The `_prepareCollection()` method in `vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Dashboard/Tab/Products/Viewed.php` is used for selecting products.

We can copy some code lines from `_prepareCollection()` above. For example, in your block, use the following code below:

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productsFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productsFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productsFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productsFactory = $productsFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Getting most viewed products
     */
    public function getCollection()
    {

        $currentStoreId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();

        $collection = $this->_productsFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(
            '*'
        )->addViewsCount()->setStoreId(
                $currentStoreId
        )->addStoreFilter(
                $currentStoreId
        );
        $items = $collection->getItems();
        return $items;
    }
}
```

The initial class `\Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory` is the most important class because this class will get our products report. The `getCollection` method will return the most viewed items by current store.

In your template, you can get the items. For example:

```
<?php
    $items = $this->getCollection();
    foreach($items as $item) {
        echo $item->getName() .'<br/>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: great! thanks a lot. Is it possible to reuse the list template with the resulted collection?

Comment: Definitely, say yes.  We need to override the layout `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`. In our custom layout, we add our block and template. For example,   `<referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Boolfly\Product\Block\Index"
                   name="most.viewed" as="most.viewed"
                   template="Boolfly_Product::most_viewed_product.phtml" before="-" />
        </referenceContainer>`

Comment: can you explain this ans as it its very easy for a beginner who needs implement it!thank you